# How to encrypting settings.xml values?

Tags: maven, encryption

Can somebody give me a hint how to encrypt some values (Strings)?

The user should not be able to read the contents of the file by opening it with an texteditor but the Programm should be able to decrypt the values.

How would I do that?

Comment: Learn about _keys_.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe/

Comment: If the user can run the code, the user can access anything the code can access.  All you can do is make it harder.

Comment: @SLaks you are correct, but it sounds like the latter option is exactly what OP is trying to do. Encrypting the settings is one of the best ways to make it harder for a user to mess with stuff. Is your opionon: nothing is completely safe, so you shouldn't bother trying to hide anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you need only to encrypt your settings.xml, execute:

```
mvn --encrypt-password <password>
```

You will get the encrypted password like this:

```
{COQLCE6DU6GtcS5P=}
```

You can use this password in you settings.xml:

```
<settings>
 ...
    <servers>
    ...
        <server>
          <id>my.server</id>
          <username>foo</username>
          <password>{COQLCE6DU6GtcS5P=}</password>
        </server>
    ...
    </servers>
...
</settings>
```

For more info check this post: [how to secure and encrypt setting.xml paswords file in maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661480/how-to-secure-and-encrypt-setting-xml-paswords-file-in-maven/46661583#46661583)

Answer (score -1):

You will need to encrypt the data that is stored on disk, and decrypt it at runtime when reading the settings from disk. How you do this will depend on the programming language you are using. Frameworks like JAVA and .NET have built-in encryption libraries (e.g. [.NET AES documentation and example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx). For most popular programming languages, you can probably find 3rd party libraries for different private key encryption algorithms. Otherwise, you will need to implement your own. If you have to do that, I would look at using AES. You can find decent information to get you started [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)

Comment: @zaph 1. if you have no other choice, there is nothing wrong with implementing your own encryption. Unless you need to be really really secure. 2. In this case, it sounds like you can hardcode the key as a constant inside of the program source, assuming it is compiled. Yes they can get that by decompiling, but again, nothing is 100% secure. 3. It depends, but yes the current standard is the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES).

Comment: @zaph 4. AES is a varient of the Rijndael encryption algorithm. it is a type of private key encryption algorithm (also called a secret key algorithm.) as opposed to public key algorithms (or asymetric key encryption algorithms). There are other private key algorithms, AES is not the only one, it isn't "usually called secret key encryption"

Comment: From the sounds of the post, the OP needs to be able to read the encrypted info in his program. This means they cannot use any implementation of AES to just encrypt this info themselves. They need to have one that provides some sort of API for them to work with. Otherwise, they would have to make system calls to have the info decrypted, and then manage a copy of the plaintext via the OS. Which would be way less secure, and open to attacks. I wasn't suggesting they implement it themselves, UNLESS there are no existing implementations.

Comment: I am not talking about creating their own algorithm, I am talking about implementing an existing one. Of course they shouldn't create their own algorithm unless they are a cryptographic engineer.

Comment: You are telling me that every single programming language has an available API that is an expertly created implementation of an appropriate encryption algorithm? You don't even know what language OP programming language is in. How can you possibly know an implementation definitely exists. What do you want them to do if an implementation doesn't exist then? If you are going to knock what I am saying, please provide a more appropriate solution.

Comment: No, I am just trying to be realistic and helpful with my answer.

Comment: The proper solution is to use an encryption implementation from the language provider or well respected source. In today's world (2017) if a language does not support basic cryptographic primitives as hashes and algorithms such as SHA2 and AES then don't use it for cryptographic operations. A naive, to cryptography, user should not implement a cryptographic primitive, that is just not secure. Suggesting it is reasonable is putting the users at risk.

Comment: "Otherwise, you will need to implement your own." Once again an answer that would be great has "snatched failure from the jaws of success" by adding a little to much information that is suspect.