# how to secure and encrypt setting.xml paswords file in maven?

Tags: maven, security

How to secure server/proxy settings in settings.xml in maven?

I assume this is mostly about login and passwords stored there and I assume that those can't be placed placed there explicitly, should they be stored in env variables/etc?

how should example of a secure settings.xml look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options:

**1)If you need only use in settings.xml:**

Execute:

```
mvn --encrypt-password <password>
```

You will get the encrypted password like this:

```
{COQLCE6DU6GtcS5P=}
```

You can use this password in you settings.xml:

```
<settings>
 ...
    <servers>
    ...
        <server>
          <id>my.server</id>
          <username>foo</username>
          <password>{COQLCE6DU6GtcS5P=}</password>
        </server>
    ...
    </servers>
...
</settings>
```

**2)If you need to use in multiple uses:**

Execute:

```
mvn --encrypt-master-password <password>
```

Yo will get the encrypted password like this:

```
{jSMOWnoPFgsHVpMvz5VrIt5kRbzGpI8u+9EF1iFQyJQ=}
```

Store this password in the **${user.home}/.m2/settings-security.xml** it should look like:

```
<settingsSecurity>
      <master>{jSMOWnoPFgsHVpMvz5VrIt5kRbzGpI8u+9EF1iFQyJQ=}</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, can I somehow secure the master password location even more than in the /.m2/settings-security.xml file?

Comment: I edited my post, if you need to use more than in settings.xml you can create the file /.m2/settings-security.xml

Comment: I have a password that contains both '!' and '@' symbol. Do I need to escape these like this- \!\password\@\text ?

Answer (score 3):

If a `settings.xml` is shared (maybe it's a 'team' file, maybe it sits on a shared build/CI box) then sensitivie details within it - specifically passwords - can (**should** :) be encrypted.

1. Create a master password:

   ```
   mvn --encrypt-master-password <password>
   ```
2. Add the master password to `settings-security.xml`
3. Encrypt your password

   ```
   mvn --encrypt-password <password>
   ```
4. Add the encrypted value to your `settings.xml`

More details [in the docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html).

Comment: Master password is indeed required. Can it be even further secured than just encrypted hash in settings-security.xml?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. This approach does rely on keeping your `settings-security.xml` _safe_. The docs make mention of this: "For an extra level of security, you can encourage your developers to store the encrypted master password on a removable storage device like a USB hard drive".

Comment: If you using on a CI server you should let handle that the CI tool for example jenkins using config file provider im combination with credentials store...

Answer (score 1):

Latest Maven version require settings-security.xml file to be in same folder as settings.xml.

Below command is used to create one encryption key based on initial password.

**step 1:**

```
mvn --encrypt-master-password <TYPE_YOUR_RANDOM_PASSWORD_HERE>
```

*then*
whatever you get in result {xxx=}, copy that and paste in settings-security.xml

eg.

```
 <settingsSecurity>
        <master>{wf345sdfsdfasdaddf4343+xA=}</master>
 </settingsSecurity>
```

**step 2:** run below command to encrypt your actual password

```
mvn --encrypt-password <ACTUAL_SERVER_PASSWORD>
```

*then*
whatever you get in result paste that in your settings.xml  attribute.
eg.

```
<server>
      <id>maven-xyz-public</id>
       <username>user_name</username>
      <password>{wfdsff43534sdfdsfd=}</password>
</server>
```

Comment: Are you soure about your first statement? "Latest Maven version require settings-security.xml file to be in same folder as settings.xml." 
I am running maven 3.8.5 and switch to project specific settings.xml: "mvn -s c:\path\to\my\settings.xml ..." but maven requires my settings-security.xml still in my users home directory c:\users\<me>\.m2

Comment: I Remember it was 3.6 or 3.5 version when i posted this comment.